# Will using <span> instead of <h> tags for heading affect the way Google caches them?

Tags: html, css, seo

Will using `<span class="heading">` instead of `<h>` tags affect Google search engine optimization?

I am building a website and I styled the headings and subheadings with `<span>`. Then I realized will Google find them without the `<h1>` tag?

Will span work or should i use ?

```
<span class="main-heading">Text here</span>.
```

Or

```
<h1>Heading</h1>.
```

Comment: Search Google for `SEO`.

Comment: Visually there's not much difference, but `<h>` tags and others are used by the search engines, screen readers and other applications to work out how the document is structured. If you care about SEO, use the right tags.

Comment: @ Mike W: what if i do it like this <h1><span class="main-heading">Heading</span></h1>

Comment: @Timothy what Mike Says is totally right.. why you using an extra element like here `span`?

Comment: `<h1><span class="main-heading">Heading</span></h1>` is technically OK, but looks unnecessary. If you need special styling for a particular `h1`, you can do this: `<h1 class="main-heading">Heading</h1>`.

Comment: Your can style h1 just like a span right? no cross browser problems

Comment: not even SEO - if you have content that is a heading for other content, mark it up as a heading. It's common sense.

Comment: In your style sheet you can style an h1 just like any other tag!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the aspect of design & development there is no matter what tag you have used.

But, from the aspect of SEO there is really a big difference between `<span>` and `<h>` tags.

Generally, `<h>` tags are used for SEO purpose. Search engines consider `<h>` tags more important than `<span>`. The Search engine indexed your web page text as a **title** if it enclosed between `<h>` tag.

For More Detail please visit [THIS SITE](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/2014-important-h1-tag-seo/106613/).

Also, if you want to use `<h>` tags without major changes than you can do following:

HTML :

```
<h1>
    <span class="main-heading"></span>
</h1>
<h2>
    <span class="sub-heading"></span>
</h2>
```

CSS :

```
h1, .main-heading { font-size:30px; }
h2, .sub-heading { font-size:26px; }
```

Comment: Thanks im going to do it this way

Comment: Why would you not just set the class on the h1, if you wanted to use classes? Like so: `<h1 class="main-heading">`